# jquery sending post data without defining url

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to send data via ajax or post and not to define url? This is the code I am trying to work:

```
$("#gll_delete").click(function(){
    var gll = $("#gll").val();

    var gll_string = gll.split(' ');
    var gll_id = gll_string[0];
    console.log(gll_id);
    var data = "gll_id=" + gll_id; 
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",        
        data : data
    });
});
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: And where would like to send your data to?

Comment: It's the same as trying to send a letter and not to write the recipient address.

Comment: I am using jQuery File Upload 6.5, and I need to data to delete function, but if I put url function is called twice and not working. Long story short, this was a long shot do something I don't understand quite well :D

Comment: If you want to delete something in the server, then you have to tell the server to do that.
So, the url should look like something like this: `http://server/delete.php?id=X`

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a destination for this request. If it should be the same page (like an empty action attribute on a html form reacts) you could do:

```
url: location.href
```

Comment: I have found leaving a "" also works.