# ajax POST produces SyntaxError only in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, curl

Everything is working perfect for all browers except *IE*, where it does not even seem like the post is made to the `Server` and a `SyntaxError` is logged to the console.

I have a simple registration page on a *WordPress* portal which uses `cURL` to post the registration form to another machine.

`JS`:

```
$("#formSubmitButton").click(function () {
    $('#activity').show();

    AttachValidation($("#form"));
    if ($("#form").valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '', 
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                ProcessResponse(data, "form");
            },
            dataType:'json'
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#activity').hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

`JS` for error handling:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    $('#activity').hide();
    toastr.error('An unhandled error has occured. Please contact customer support');
    console.error(jqxhr);
    console.error(exception);
});
```

Some *WordPress* `PHP` for the `REST client`:

```
$this->acceptType       = 'application/json';   

protected function executePost ($ch)
{
    if (!is_string($this->requestBody))
    {
        $this->buildPostBody();
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->requestBody);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $this->doExecute($ch);  
}

protected function setCurlOpts (&$curlHandle)
{
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: ' . $this->acceptType, 'api-key: ' . $this->ApiKey));
}

protected function doExecute (&$curlHandle)
{
    $this->setCurlOpts($curlHandle);
    $this->responseBody = curl_exec($curlHandle);
    $this->responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);

    curl_close($curlHandle);
}
```

Also *IE* dev tool's network capture does not show an `HTTP` post.

[image: Error as it appears on IE's dev tools]

Pretty normal stuff. The server is returning json correctly and all browsers can read it. Only *IE* has this error, the *IE* dev tools doesnt really let me see if the server is even being called.

Ive tried to set the cache to false on this call, amongst others without any luck.

Basically my entire setup works, it is only *IE* that has an issue.  I am on *IE11*.   I had a report from an user on a different IE version that the form did post but instead of my site showing the response text it asked the user to download it as a .json file.   So maybe its all related.

Thank you!

Comment: On what line does IE throw the error?  Also, what version of IE?

Comment: what's the error? have you tried adding some ajax error handling? IE dev tools has a network tab. Hard to troubleshoot without more details

Comment: I have updated the issue description.    Currently on IE 11,  devtools network capture shows no POST.  Page just raises the error immediately.

Comment: There's no URL, where do you suppose the ajax call ends up ?

Comment: you have an error above the one you have expanded. any more above that? It's usually a good idea to start with the first error and work your way down.

Comment: Also, you set the acceptType to JSON, but ajax with serialize() is generally sent as form/url-encoded, not application/json

Comment: @MrOBrian  I updated the screenshot. There are no errors before them,  it was just a bad screenshot.

Comment: I'm still not clear on when the error happens. What line is causing the error? I'm thinking maybe it's the call to `serialize()` but it could also be AttachValidation, or maybe the way you're constructing the ajax request is invalid. It's tough to say without knowing what line causes the error.

Comment: I have uncommented everything in that JS block, so that it just runs the ajax call, and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue for this setup was extremely simple.   My setup worked for all browsers,  but the fact that the javascript was stating an empty url for the ajax POST it was throwing IE off.   The url was safely being read and setup by the underlying REST client code (PHP)

I removed the url parameter from the JS and it worked for IE, while not breaking the other browsers.

Thanks everyone for your comments.

```
$("#formSubmitButton").click(function () {
    $('#activity').show();

    AttachValidation($("#form"));
    if ($("#form").valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                ProcessResponse(data, "form");
            },
            dataType:'json'
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#activity').hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: was helpful for me :) removing the property made IE11 happy

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was really doing my head in!  I had (wrongly) thought the `url` was mandatory so used `'#'`, which Chrome was happy with in dev but then IE11 barfed on.  Removed it completely like you suggested, and wuhoo :)

Comment: If you cannot just remove the url completely, as in jQuery $.post, use `location.href` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9634391/733092.