# Dropdown menu Ajax call doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the value of the selected item of a dropdown menu to update the same page (form) with an Ajax call accordingly. For example to display extra form fields based on the user choice, like a new set of input fields, if "NEW" is selected, but I'm not this far, yet.

Form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form" id="insertItem">
    <fieldset>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
            </dt>
            <dd>
                <select size="1" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer">
                    <option value="">- Choose -</option>
                    <option value="">-- NEW --</option>
                    <option value="">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="">Option 4</option>
                </select>
            </dd>
        </dl>
       (...)
       more items
       (...)
</form>
```

Script:

```
$('#manufacturer').change(function() {
        var val = $("#manufacturer option:selected").text()
        $.ajax({
            url : "path_to/file.php",
            type : "GET",
            data : { selectedValue : val},
            success : function(response) {
                console.log("check " + response);
//            $('#test').html(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('Error');
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
```

The console shows nothing, no errors either. It's also not showing up in Network tab. What did I do wrong? (jQuery 1.12.4 is included properly and works.)

Comment: Do you see the ajax call in the [`network`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?hl=en) tab in Chrome?

Comment: I'm using Firebug, but no.. it's not firing.

Comment: You're not specifying url in your ajax call. This is not a form post but an ajax call to somewhere.

Comment: I've seen script examples without URL, that's what I tried to do.

Comment: It was an issue with Niceforms. It blocked the `change()` event, so the script didn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the url in your ajax call. without URL it does'nt work.

```
$('#manufacturer').change(function () {
    myVal = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
        url         : 'ajax_process.php',
        method      : 'post',
        data        :
        {
            variable : myVal
        },
        success     : function(response)
        {

        });
    });
```

Comment: So are the examples with no url wrong? Or what would that look like?

Comment: @dly Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634343/jquery-sending-post-data-without-defining-url However there are other issues with your code, apart from the url.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 syntaxe for ajax call.

```
$.ajax("url", [setting])
```

Or

```
$.ajax([setting])
```

But in the second ways, you need to specify url in the setting's object.

And $(this).val() was wrong is the scope, save "this" before ajax call :

```
$('#manufacturer').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val() ;
    $.ajax({
         url :  "myurl",
        type:'POST',
        data : { selectedValue : val},
        success : function(response) {
            console.log("check " + response);
//          $('#test').html(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Error');
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```

NB :
With your current html, $(this).val() will always be equals to empty string.
If you want the text of the selected option use :

```
var val = $("#manufacturer option:selected").text()
```

Comment: I tried your way, but still doesn't do anything. I included an already working php file, but it doesn't show up in the console or network.

Comment: @dly In your php are you expecting a parameter called selectedValue? Did you set the url?

Comment: Yes. My guess is that the script doesn't get called at all. Even with c&p from a working one it doesn't.

Comment: Check the request in your Net tab using inspector tool. If there's an error you should see http code and message.

Comment: had you checked console errors? the code posted by me worked fine, you might be missing something obvious. Are you sure you added jQuery to the page and javascript is enabled?